# How do I use custom bullet order in Lyx?

Tags: formatting, lyx

For example, I am trying to make bullet points and the first bullet point are
Numbers, then Parens around lower-case letters, Uppercase letters, etc... I want to make my own, e.g. 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, or I, i, ii, *... 
just anything other than the regular options.

Comment: Welcome! No idea about LyX, but wherever is applicable, load `enumitem` and set up whatever custom lists you want. Don't know if LyX has some whizzy interface for this or if you need to use a red box or whatever. (I've never used LyX as you can doubtless tell.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Document -> Settings -> Modules`, choose `Customizable Lists (enumitem)` and add it.

Then go to the beginning of the item whose bullet you want to change, right click on it and choose `Custom item`, click in the box that appears, and choose `Insert -> TeX code` and insert `label=\arabic*` of whatever you like.

For more info, see here: [LyX.org - Enumitem](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/Enumitem).

P.S. = I've the Italian version of LyX 2.2.2, please let me know if the names of the options I have indicated are correctly translated.